# Como fazer o uso do deferred e when nesta aplicação?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei 3 funções, onde cada uma faz uma requisição `ajax`

- A primeira: `checkFila()` verifica se existem agendamentos pendentes, se sim, chama a segunda.
- A segunda: `sendEmail()` envia o e-mail que está na fila e no sucesso da mesma, chamo a terceira.
- A terceira: `limpaFila()` responsável por limpar.

O problema é que a **segunda** e **terceira** funções não são executadas. Pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi que é necessário usar `deferred` / `when` porém não sei como.

```js
function checkFila() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "checkFila.php",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
         var statusRetorno = data.retorno;
         var idAgendamento = data.idAgendamento;
         sendEmail(idAgendamento);
         if (statusRetorno) {
            //if( !( typeof idTimerCheckFila=="undefined" ))
            //clearInterval( idTimerCheckFila ); // limpa o timer
            // reinicializar timer
            //idTimerCheckFila = setInterval( function(){ checkFila(); }, 120000 ); 
         }
      },
      error: function() {
         bootbox.alert("Falha de Conexão!<br />Não foi possível efetuar sua requisição.<br/>Aguarde alguns instantes e faça uma nova tentativa.");
      }
   });
};

function sendEmail(numID) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "sendEmail.php=" + id_agendamento,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
         var statusRetorno = data.retorno;
         if (statusRetorno) {
            table_fila_emails.ajax.reload();
            limpaFila();
         }
      },
      error: function() {
         bootbox.alert("Falha de Conexão!<br />Não foi possível efetuar sua requisição.<br/>Aguarde alguns instantes e faça uma nova tentativa.");
      }
   });
};


function limpaFila() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "clearFila.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
         var statusRetorno = data.retorno;
         if (statusRetorno)
            table_fila_emails.ajax.reload();
      },
      error: function() {
         bootbox.alert("Falha de Conexão!<br />Não foi possível efetuar sua requisição.<br/>Aguarde alguns instantes e faça uma nova tentativa.");
      }
   });
};
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so] Francisco! antes de mais nada sugiro a você, como criar um [mre] para poder elaborar uma boa pergunta, pois falta informações! Portanto, já considerou a tentativa de olhar o console do seu navegador para verificar qual erro é retornado? sem o uso do deferred/when?

Comment: Vale ressaltar que você pode debugar seu código, percorrendo ele passo-a-passo, cada função, cada etapa, etc.. Ex: `success: function(data) { console.log ("cheguei aqui!"); ... }` e assim sucessivamente!

Comment: Entendo suas considerações mas é pelo console do navegador que vi que somente a primeira função, checkFila() é executada.  Só esqueci de mencionar que essa função é executada a cada 2 minutos pelo evento de tempo setinterval().